# How to get updated value of EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to android and working on a basic screen to use a web-service with android application.

I am posting values using `AsyncTask` and fetching the result from the webservice. It works fine until displaying the returned value. While displaying the `Toast` Message on click, I get old value of `TextView` `resultReturned`

```
public class TestPost extends Activity{

private TextView result = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_screen);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultReturned);


    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] strPost = new String[]{"value1", "value2"};
            SendAsyncRequest asyncSend = new SendAsyncRequest();
            asyncSend.execute(strPost);
            // ResultView retains old value and gets correct value on second click
            String returned = result.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), returned, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
    }); 
  }

public class SendAsyncRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private String fetchedData = "";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params  ) {
        // perform async task
        return fetchedData;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            setReturedValue(result);
    }

}
private void setReturedValue(String data){
    result.setText(data);
}
```

So, how do I get the updated text value of the TextView?

Comment: The `execute(...)` method of `AsyncTask` returns immediately so your `Toast` will always show the current text of the `TextView`

Comment: @Squonk, can you please elaborate? You mean to say that, as AsynkTask returns immediately so before my HttpRequest get completed the Toast Message gets visible?

Comment: i guess @RajaReddy PolamReddy is right.

Comment: @Cyberpks : Yes. An `AsyncTask` is exactly what it says it is. The `doInBackground` method runs asynchronously on a separate `Thread`. This means the execute method returns immediately once the `Thread` has started and execution of the following code continues as normal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String[] strPost = new String[]{"value1", "value2"};
        SendAsyncRequest asyncSend = new SendAsyncRequest();
        asyncSend.execute(strPost);
        // ResultView retains old value and gets correct value on second click
        String jsonResult;
        try {
            jsonResult=asyncSend.get();

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
});
```

And return your Json String in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: thanks man, that worked like charm!!! I found somewhere that `.get()` is used to wait until the Async request gets completed. And you helped me apply that correctly.

Comment: @Cyberpks : The use of `get()` is a blocking call and should never be called on the main (UI) thread. Not only does it make the whole point of using an `AsyncTask` redundant but any long running operations on the `AsyncTask` worker thread could possibly cause an ANR situation. I've yet to find anyone who can come up with a good reason for using `get()` and I've no idea why it was added as a method for `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @Squonk can you explain better scenario if I need data fetched from this background thread in my next activity then how to get it.

Comment: @Squonk, your reason seems to be valid, but is there any other way to do this? I've not tested this `get()` method yet for longer waiting requests, but yes it can cause an ANR situation.

Comment: @Cyberpks (and @ved) : As suggested by RajaReddy you should be doing things in `onPostExecute` - that's what it's for. You can parse the JSON if you want, alternatively save it in SharedPreferences or database. You could even pass it to another `Activity` as an `Intent` extra used with `startActivity`.

Comment: @ved, Squonk has a valid reason as Async request can take longer to return a response, and until then Activity Manager will try to suppress it and avoid waiting for longer duration. Ref http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: @Squonk can you give me idea how to get data from AsyncTask class  if my AsyncTask class is not in the same Activity class, it is as a separate class.

Comment: @ved : Is there a reason your `AsyncTask` isn't an inner class of your `Activity`? Is it re-used by other `Activities`? If not then make it an inner class. Otherwise there are many questions about doing it here on SO. One way is to define an interface in your `Activity` and create a constructor in your `AsyncTask` which takes the `Activity` as a parameter. You can then call the interface method in `onPostExecute`. It's a dangerous approach though as the `Activity` may have been destroyed.

Comment: @Squonk yes I have using this AsyncTask in multiple Activities.I've try to create a Interface and make my AsyncTask as abstract then call the interface method in my Activity but it is still waiting for result.Is this approach is correct or you suggest any other.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask takes time to get response from request, Show toast message in postExecute() method, like this, and remove from onclick.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

Comment: I have done that thing previously what you suggested here, but I have to actually parse a `JSON` string and that must be present in the `Click` event. Toast message thing is just an example.